# Steps to generate REST API Documentation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to generate Swagger-based REST API documentation (UI) for some of my existing REST API.

What are the necessary steps or prerequisite for it? I'm working on Windows OS.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Do you have an existing API or are you looking to design one? If you have an existing API, which development language and framework/libraries do you use?

Comment: I have an existing API, designed using JAX-RS, Jersey Libs on Maven. I need steps for generating swagger based UI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/) is our own library for integration with JAX-RS projects

We provide a [simple tutorial](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5) to explain how to integrate it with your code. It's fairly straightforward. The [annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) are documented as well to help you understand what should be added and where.

When you complete the above steps, you'll have an output of a `swagger.json` and `swagger.yaml` file. At this  point, you'll want to integrate [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) with your application. There are various way of doing so. One way is to integrate it with your build process as we have in our samples.

The combination of the two plugins will do it for you:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>swagger-ui</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>wget</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/master.tar.gz</url>
          <unpack>true</unpack>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}/swagger-ui-master/dist</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>index.html</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

You just need to make sure to run the `package` goal as well, so something like `mvn package install` if you want to install it (but that depend on your development process).

Comment: The pom.xml. Just updated the plugin configuration to point to the master release of the UI.

Comment: Not enough info. That's when doing what? What's your full pom.xml? The plugin should be executed with the `package` goal.

Comment: You're digressing from the original question and it would be very difficult to answer it all in comments. Feel free to send a post to our google group.

Comment: Hello, I maven build successfully! where is the swagger,json created?

Comment: It's not created, it's generated at runtime. It will be hosted at the context root of your application. That's pretty much documented all over the place in the repository.

Comment: What if I use Dynamic Web Project and I don't have pom.xml?

Comment: There are some details in the project's wiki as to what to do when your project is not maven based.

Answer (score 7):

Swagger provides a few options on how to architect your API documentation.

First you need to understand it's divided in two pieces:

CORE is used to generate a JSON with relevant information about your API.
This JSON follows swagger template.

INTERFACE will then read that JSON and generate HTML

First you'll annotate your controllers and endpoints, you'll need 'swagger-core' and 'swagger-annotations' for that.

Then you have two options:

a) Provide an endpoint to generate and serve JSON and use swagger-ui to read that endpoint to generate HTML

b) Use the maven plugin swagger-maven to generate the JSON and the HTML when compiling.

More info at:

http://swagger.io/

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec#additional-libraries

If you are using Spring I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/springfox

If you prefer the Maven plugin see https://github.com/kongchen

Answer (score 1):

You can use following steps :

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.viquar./groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messenger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messenger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Swagger documentations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Download:**

You can use the swagger-ui code AS-IS! No need to build or recompile--just clone this repo and use the pre-built files in the dist folder. If you like swagger-ui as-is, stop here.

http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/

Following steps give you end to end example

DatabaseClass.java

```
package org.viquar.database;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.viquar.model.Message;
import org.viquar.model.Profile;

public class DatabaseClass {

    private static Map<Long, Message> messages = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<>();


    public static Map<Long, Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public static Map<String, Profile> getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }
}
```

DataNotFoundException.java

```
package org.viquar.exception;

public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6328286661536343936L;


    public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.java

```
package org.viquar.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.viquar.model.ErrorMessage;

@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException ex) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(), 404, "http://localhost:8080/JerseyRestPoc.Viquar.poc");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(errorMessage)
                .build();
    }

}
```

GenericExceptionMapper.java

```
package org.viquar.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import org.viquar.model.ErrorMessage;

// This class intentionally doesn't have the @Provider annotation.
// It has been disabled in order to try out other ways of throwing exceptions in JAX-RS

// @Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(), 500, "http://localhost:8080/JerseyRestPoc.Viquar.poc");
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(errorMessage)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment.java

```
package org.viquar.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Comment {


    private long id;
    private String message;
    private Date created;
    private String author;

    public Comment() {

    }

    public Comment(long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }



}
```

ErrorMessage.java

```
package org.viquar.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorMessage {

    private String errorMessage;
    private int errorCode;
    private String documentation;

    public ErrorMessage() {

    }

    public ErrorMessage(String errorMessage, int errorCode, String documentation) {
        super();
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.documentation = documentation;
    }
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }
    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public String getDocumentation() {
        return documentation;
    }
    public void setDocumentation(String documentation) {
        this.documentation = documentation;
    }


}
```

Link.java

```
package org.viquar.model;

public class Link {
    private String link;
    private String rel;

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    public String getRel() {
        return rel;
    }
    public void setRel(String rel) {
        this.rel = rel;
    }


}
```

Message.java

```
package org.viquar.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    private long id;
    private String message;
    private Date created;
    private String author;
    private Map<Long, Comment> comments = new HashMap<>();
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public Map<Long, Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Map<Long, Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<Link> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(List<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public void addLink(String url, String rel) {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.setLink(url);
        link.setRel(rel);
        links.add(link);
    }


}
```

Profile.java

```
package org.viquar.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class Profile {

    private long id;
    private String profileName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date created;

    public Profile() {

    }

    public Profile(long id, String profileName, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.profileName = profileName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProfileName() {
        return profileName;
    }
    public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }


}
```

ProfileResource.java

```
package org.viquar.resources;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.viquar.model.Profile;
import org.viquar.service.ProfileService;

@Path("/profiles")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProfileResource {

    private ProfileService profileService = new ProfileService();



    @GET
    public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
        return profileService.getAllProfiles();
    }

    @POST
    public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
        return profileService.addProfile(profile);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{profileName}")
    public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("profileName") String profileName) {
        return profileService.getProfile(profileName);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{profileName}")
    public Profile updateProfile(@PathParam("profileName") String profileName, Profile profile) {
        profile.setProfileName(profileName);
        return profileService.updateProfile(profile);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{profileName}")
    public void deleteProfile(@PathParam("profileName") String profileName) {
        profileService.removeProfile(profileName);
    }



}
```

MessageResource.java

```
package org.viquar.resources;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.viquar.model.Message;
import org.viquar.resources.beans.MessageFilterBean;
import org.viquar.service.MessageService;
//
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;


@Path("/messages")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "/messages", description = "Operation about orders")
public class MessageResource {

    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

    @GET
    public List<Message> getMessages(@BeanParam MessageFilterBean filterBean) {

        if (filterBean.getYear() > 0) {
            return messageService.getAllMessagesForYear(filterBean.getYear());
        }
        if (filterBean.getStart() >= 0 && filterBean.getSize() > 0) {
            return messageService.getAllMessagesPaginated(filterBean.getStart(), filterBean.getSize());
        }
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }

    @POST
    public Response addMessage(Message message, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        Message newMessage = messageService.addMessage(message);
        String newId = String.valueOf(newMessage.getId());
        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newId).build();
        return Response.created(uri)
                .entity(newMessage)
                .build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message updateMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id, Message message) {
        message.setId(id);
        return messageService.updateMessage(message);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public void deleteMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id) {
        messageService.removeMessage(id);
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns user details", notes = "Returns a complete list of users details with a date of last modification.", response = Message.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of user detail", response = Message.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User with given username does not exist"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")
        })
    public Message getMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        Message message = messageService.getMessage(id);
        message.addLink(getUriForSelf(uriInfo, message), "self");
        message.addLink(getUriForProfile(uriInfo, message), "profile");
        message.addLink(getUriForComments(uriInfo, message), "comments");

        return message;

    }

    private String getUriForComments(UriInfo uriInfo, Message message) {
        URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
                .path(MessageResource.class)
                .path(MessageResource.class, "getCommentResource")
                .path(CommentResource.class)
                .resolveTemplate("messageId", message.getId())
                .build();
        return uri.toString();
    }

    private String getUriForProfile(UriInfo uriInfo, Message message) {
        URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
             .path(ProfileResource.class)
             .path(message.getAuthor())
             .build();
        return uri.toString();
    }

    private String getUriForSelf(UriInfo uriInfo, Message message) {
        String uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
         .path(MessageResource.class)
         .path(Long.toString(message.getId()))
         .build()
         .toString();
        return uri;
    }




    @Path("/{messageId}/comments")
    public CommentResource getCommentResource() {
        return new CommentResource();
    }

}
```

InjectDemoResource.java

```
package org.viquar.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.CookieParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/injectdemo")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class InjectDemoResource {

    @GET
    @Path("annotations")
    public String getParamsUsingAnnotations(@MatrixParam("param") String matrixParam,
                                            @HeaderParam("authSessionID") String header,
                                            @CookieParam("name") String cookie) {
        return "Matrix param: " + matrixParam + " Header param: " + header + " Cookie param: " + cookie;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("context")
    public String getParamsUsingContext(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {

        String path = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        String cookies = headers.getCookies().toString();
        return "Path : " + path + " Cookies: " + cookies;
    }




}
```

CommentResource.java

```
package org.viquar.resources;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.viquar.model.Comment;
import org.viquar.service.CommentService;

@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public class CommentResource {

    private CommentService commentService = new CommentService();

    @GET
    public List<Comment> getAllComments(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId) {
        return commentService.getAllComments(messageId);
    }

    @POST
    public Comment addComment(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, Comment comment) {
        return commentService.addComment(messageId, comment);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{commentId}")
    public Comment updateComment(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, @PathParam("commentId") long id, Comment comment) {
        comment.setId(id);
        return commentService.updateComment(messageId, comment);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{commentId}")
    public void deleteComment(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, @PathParam("commentId") long commentId) {
        commentService.removeComment(messageId, commentId);
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/{commentId}")
    public Comment getMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, @PathParam("commentId") long commentId) {
        return commentService.getComment(messageId, commentId);
    }

}
```

MessageFilterBean.java

```
package org.viquar.resources.beans;

import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

public class MessageFilterBean {

     private @QueryParam("year") int year;
     private @QueryParam("start") int start;
     private @QueryParam("size") int size;

     public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

CommentService.java

```
package org.viquar.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import org.viquar.database.DatabaseClass;
import org.viquar.model.Comment;
import org.viquar.model.ErrorMessage;
import org.viquar.model.Message;

public class CommentService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages = DatabaseClass.getMessages();

    public List<Comment> getAllComments(long messageId) {
        Map<Long, Comment> comments = messages.get(messageId).getComments();
        return new ArrayList<Comment>(comments.values());
    }

    public Comment getComment(long messageId, long commentId) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage("Not found", 404, "http://CosineOTC.Viquar.poc");
        Response response = Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(errorMessage)
                .build();

        Message message = messages.get(messageId);
        if (message == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(response);
        }
        Map<Long, Comment> comments = messages.get(messageId).getComments();
        Comment comment = comments.get(commentId);
        if (comment == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException(response);
        }
        return comment;
    }

    public Comment addComment(long messageId, Comment comment) {
        Map<Long, Comment> comments = messages.get(messageId).getComments();
        comment.setId(comments.size() + 1);
        comments.put(comment.getId(), comment);
        return comment;
    }




    public Comment updateComment(long messageId, Comment comment) {
        Map<Long, Comment> comments = messages.get(messageId).getComments();
        if (comment.getId() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        comments.put(comment.getId(), comment);
        return comment;
    }

    public Comment removeComment(long messageId, long commentId) {
        Map<Long, Comment> comments = messages.get(messageId).getComments();
        return comments.remove(commentId);
    }

}
```

MessageService.java

```
package org.viquar.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.viquar.database.DatabaseClass;
import org.viquar.exception.DataNotFoundException;
import org.viquar.model.Message;

public class MessageService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages = DatabaseClass.getMessages();

    public MessageService() {
        messages.put(1L, new Message(1, "Hello World", "ViquarKhan"));
        messages.put(2L, new Message(2, "Hello Jersey", "Shahbazkhan"));
        messages.put(3L, new Message(3, "Hello Cosine", "Snehaghosh"));
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values()); 
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessagesForYear(int year) {
        List<Message> messagesForYear = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (Message message : messages.values()) {
            cal.setTime(message.getCreated());
            if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year) {
                messagesForYear.add(message);
            }
        }
        return messagesForYear;
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessagesPaginated(int start, int size) {
        ArrayList<Message> list = new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
        if (start + size > list.size()) return new ArrayList<Message>();
        return list.subList(start, start + size); 
    }


    public Message getMessage(long id) {
        Message message = messages.get(id);
        if (message == null) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Message with id " + id + " not found");
        }
        return message;
    }

    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        message.setId(messages.size() + 1);
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message updateMessage(Message message) {
        if (message.getId() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message removeMessage(long id) {
        return messages.remove(id);
    }
}
```

ProfileService.java

```
package org.viquar.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.viquar.database.DatabaseClass;
import org.viquar.model.Profile;

public class ProfileService {

    private Map<String, Profile> profiles = DatabaseClass.getProfiles();

    public ProfileService() {
        profiles.put("Viquar", new Profile(1L, "Viquar", "Viquar", "Khan"));
        profiles.put("Shahbaz", new Profile(2L, "Shahbaz", "Shahbaz", "Khan"));
        profiles.put("Sneha", new Profile(3L, "Sneha", "Sneha", "Ghosh"));
    }

    public List<Profile> getAllProfiles() {
        return new ArrayList<Profile>(profiles.values()); 
    }

    public Profile getProfile(String profileName) {
        return profiles.get(profileName);
    }

    public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
        profile.setId(profiles.size() + 1);
        profiles.put(profile.getProfileName(), profile);
        return profile;
    }

    public Profile updateProfile(Profile profile) {
        if (profile.getProfileName().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        profiles.put(profile.getProfileName(), profile);
        return profile;
    }

    public Profile removeProfile(String profileName) {
        return profiles.remove(profileName);
    }

}
```

SwaggerRestApp.java

package org.viquar.swegger;

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.config.ConfigFactory;
import com.wordnik.swagger.config.ScannerFactory;
import com.wordnik.swagger.config.SwaggerConfig;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.ReflectiveJaxrsScanner;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.reader.DefaultJaxrsApiReader;
import com.wordnik.swagger.reader.ClassReaders;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.viquar.resources.MessageResource;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

//@Component
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class SwaggerRestApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public SwaggerRestApp(){
        register(MessageResource.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        //register(AllExceptionMapper.class);
        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        register(ApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        register(ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
        register(ResourceListingProvider.class);

        property(MessageProperties.XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT, true);
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    /**
     * Initializes Swagger Configuration
     */
    public void initializeSwaggerConfiguration() {

        final ReflectiveJaxrsScanner scanner = new ReflectiveJaxrsScanner();
        scanner.setResourcePackage("org.viquar);
        ScannerFactory.setScanner(scanner);
        ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());
        final SwaggerConfig config = ConfigFactory.config();
        config.setApiVersion("1.0");
        config.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/messenger/cosineotc/api/v1");

    }
}
```

[image]

Because of limit issue next comment continue .....

Comment: The fact that you've hit the limit should hint you that your answer is too long. On [so], we expect complete, but also short and concise answers that answer the specific problem at hand. There are a few exceptions to this rule, but this isn't that case.

Answer (score 0):

To complete tbraun reply :

Here is [one](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/rest-api-documentation-with-swagger/) with clear demonstration (errors, annotations, etc...),
and [another one](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2013/07/11/Documenting-a-REST-API-with-Swagger-and-Spring-MVC).

I suggest you to refer to the doc : [swagger doc](http://swagger.io/) too.

BE careful taking the last version because there is some swagger properties that doesn't work with some swagger versions, like "apisOrder" to sort the api by name.

When you will test your APi, you can use swagger UI.

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Part 2 continue ...

Now you have to configure Webapp , create folder with following name and copy contents inside of folder

- Copy CSS inside of JerseyRestSSweggerPoc\src\main\webapp\css
- Copy fonts inside of JerseyRestSSweggerPoc\src\main\webapp\fonts
- Copy images inside of JerseyRestSSweggerPoc\src\main\webapp\images
- Copy lang inside of JerseyRestSSweggerPoc\src\main\webapp\lang
- Copy lib inside of JerseyRestSSweggerPoc\src\main\webapp\lib

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <link href='css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <script src='lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/underscore-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='swagger-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/highlight.7.3.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

  <!-- Some basic translations -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/translator.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/ru.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/en.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
      if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
      } else {
        url = "http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/v1/api-docs";
      }

      // Pre load translate...
      if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
        window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
      }
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: url,
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
          if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
            initOAuth({
              clientId: "your-client-id",
              clientSecret: "your-client-secret",
              realm: "your-realms",
              appName: "your-app-name", 
              scopeSeparator: ","
            });
          }

          if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
            window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
          }

          $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(e)
          });

          addApiKeyAuthorization();
        },
        onFailure: function(data) {
          log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
        },
        docExpansion: "none",
        apisSorter: "alpha",
        showRequestHeaders: false
      });

      function addApiKeyAuthorization(){
        var key = encodeURIComponent($('#input_apiKey')[0].value);
        if(key && key.trim() != "") {
            var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query");
            window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("api_key", apiKeyAuth);
            log("added key " + key);
        }
      }

      $('#input_apiKey').change(addApiKeyAuthorization);

      // if you have an apiKey you would like to pre-populate on the page for demonstration purposes...
      /*
        var apiKey = "myApiKeyXXXX123456789";
        $('#input_apiKey').val(apiKey);
      */

      window.swaggerUi.load();

      function log() {
        if ('console' in window) {
          console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
      }
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="swagger-section">
<div id='header'>
  <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
    <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io">swagger</a> -->
    <form id='api_selector'>
      <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
      <div class='input'><input placeholder="api_key" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
      <div class='input'><a id="explore" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.jsp

```
<html>
<head> 
   <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
   <title>Swagger UI</title> 
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /> 
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" /> 
   <link href='css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
   <link href='css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
   <link href='css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
   <link href='css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
   <link href='css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> 
   <script src='lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/underscore-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='swagger-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/highlight.7.3.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
   <script src='lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 

   <!-- Some basic translations --> 
   <!-- <script src='lang/translator.js' type='text/javascript'></script> --> 
   <!-- <script src='lang/ru.js' type='text/javascript'></script> --> 
   <!-- <script src='lang/en.js' type='text/javascript'></script> --> 


   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(function () { 
       var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/); 
       if (url && url.length > 1) { 
         url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]); 
       } else { 
         url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"; 
       } 

       // Pre load translate... 
       if(window.SwaggerTranslator) { 
         window.SwaggerTranslator.translate(); 
       } 
       window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({ 
         url: url, 
         dom_id: "swagger-ui-container", 
         supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'], 
         onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){ 
           if(typeof initOAuth == "function") { 
             initOAuth({ 
               clientId: "your-client-id", 
               clientSecret: "your-client-secret", 
               realm: "your-realms", 
               appName: "your-app-name",  
               scopeSeparator: "," 
             }); 
           } 

           if(window.SwaggerTranslator) { 
             window.SwaggerTranslator.translate(); 
           } 

           $('pre code').each(function(i, e) { 
             hljs.highlightBlock(e) 
           }); 

           addApiKeyAuthorization(); 
         }, 
         onFailure: function(data) { 
           log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI"); 
         }, 
         docExpansion: "none", 
         apisSorter: "alpha", 
         showRequestHeaders: false 
       }); 

       function addApiKeyAuthorization(){ 
         var key = encodeURIComponent($('#input_apiKey')[0].value); 
         if(key && key.trim() != "") { 
             var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query"); 
             window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("api_key", apiKeyAuth); 
             log("added key " + key); 
         } 
       } 

       $('#input_apiKey').change(addApiKeyAuthorization); 

       // if you have an apiKey you would like to pre-populate on the page for demonstration purposes... 
       /* 
         var apiKey = "myApiKeyXXXX123456789"; 
         $('#input_apiKey').val(apiKey); 
       */ 

       window.swaggerUi.load(); 

       function log() { 
         if ('console' in window) { 
           console.log.apply(console, arguments); 
         } 
       } 
   }); 
   </script> 
 </head> 

<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!



</body>
</html>
```

o2c.html

```
<script>
var qp = null;
if(window.location.hash) {
  qp = location.hash.substring(1);
}
else {
  qp = location.search.substring(1);
}
qp = qp ? JSON.parse('{"' + qp.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}',
  function(key, value) {
    return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) }
  ):{}

if (window.opener.swaggerUi.tokenUrl)
    window.opener.processOAuthCode(qp);
else
    window.opener.onOAuthComplete(qp);

window.close();
</script>
```

Hope it will help you .

**URL for Access**

```
http://localhost:8080/messenger//api/v1/messages/1
**Swegger** :
http://localhost:8080/messenger/
http://localhost:8080/jersey-swagger/rest/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/jersey-swagger/#!/employees/createEmployee




http://localhost:8080/messenger//api/v1/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/messenger/#!/messages/getMessage
http://localhost:8080/messenger//api/v1/messages/1


{
"author":"Viquar Khan","created":"2015-07-31T16:35:43.498",
"id":1,
"links":[
{"link":"http://localhost:8080/JerseyRestPoc//api/v1/messages/1","rel":"self"},
{"http://localhost:8080/JerseyRestPoc//api/v1/profiles/Viquar%20Khan","rel":"profile"},
{"link":"http://localhost:8080/JerseyRestPoc/api/v1/messages/1/comments/","rel":"comments"}
],
"message":"Hello World"
}
```

Inside of MessageResource.java , i  have added folowing annotations for Swagger

@Api(value = "/messages", description = "Operation about orders")